# How to start python program with a terminal window on ubuntu startup

Tags: python, ubuntu

I want to start a python program on ubuntu startup and im using session and startup option for it. But each time the system boots python program starts but without a terminal window that I need. Is there any option to force program to start with terminal window?

Comment: there is a application in applications named `Startup Applications`. use that to run

Comment: im using ubuntu 18.04 on vps with installed vncserver, there is no such application on it

Comment: checkout this [How to add a program as a startup application from a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178567/how-to-add-a-program-as-a-startup-application-from-a-terminal)

Comment: followed the guide above it still opens without a terminal window, the command im using is python3 /path/to/program/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a python application with a terminal window on startup just add it to the `Settings >> Session and Startup` with a following command `gnome-terminal -- python3 path/to/app`